# What does CSS width attribute mean in HTML table when layout is automatic?

Tags: html, css, html-table

If I specify a width for a `<th>` element in a table, what does that mean in terms of the wider table if table-layout is not specified and defaults to automatic? Does such a width specify a minimum width for the entire column? If so, where is this specified - I cannot find anything in the HTML/CSS specs that says width is interpreted this way, yet Firefox and IE both seem to interpret the width this way.

To put this in context, imagine a table of numeric data (e.g. production volumes) for the days of the week. The week days are the column headings. I want to cope with two conditions:

- There is no data for a particular day, but I don't want the width of the column to collapse to some ugly minimum. Rather, I want to set that minimum.
- When there are large numbers in columns, I want the width of the column to automatically expand to show the number in full.

When I specify a bunch of column widths as follows...

```
<tr>
<th style="width:3em">Sun</th>
<th style="width:3em">Mon</th>
<th style="width:3em">Tue</th>
...etc
</tr>
```

... I achieve the result I'm looking for. However, can I rely on this?

Comment: If you want `min-width`, why do you want to use `width` instead?

Comment: That would be because it's ages since I've used HTML, and I didn't know about `min-width` :-)

Comment: Nonetheless... the question is still valid. Does it mean that the behaviour of width is undefined in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can rely on this; it’s in the CSS spec, and browsers play by the book here. For table cells, the `width` property sets the minimum width used in the calculation of column width.

The spec is somewhat messy here, because the description of the `width` property does not say this or even refer to the description (as far as I can see), but this is described in section 17.5.2.2 [Automatic table layout](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#auto-table-layout). Item 1 in the first numbered list there says: “Calculate the minimum content width (MCW) of each cell: the formatted content may span any number of lines but may not overflow the cell box. If the specified 'width' (W) of the cell is greater than MCW, W is the minimum cell width. A value of 'auto' means that MCW is the minimum cell width.”

Comment: So... between this and your comments elsewhere... would it be your opinion that when it comes to tables, it is better to rely on the `width` property, and not the `min-width`? I guess I'll change things back to what I originally had then :-)

Comment: @omatai, yes it is certainly better to rely on a property that has a defined effect on an element (`width`).

Answer (score -1):

To set the minimum allowed width and let the fields expand wider if need be, use something like this

```
th {
  width: auto; /* This is default, but shown here for clarity */
  min-width: 100px; /* or whatever size need be */
}
```

Comment: “In CSS 2.1, the effect of 'min-width' and 'max-width' on [...] table cells [...] is undefined.” http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-min-width

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela That may be, but it does still seem to work in all browsers except IE7 and older. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/gF2KL/

Comment: “Undefined” means anything may happen. And the behavior differs from that of setting `width`, which is well-defined, so what is the point?

Comment: The point would be to get the functionality of `min-width` instead of `width`. `width` sets a firm width of the element whereas min-width allows the element to expand larger as the content needs. True anything could happen since it's undefined, but the majority of browsers react as the name `min-width` implies and future specs are unlikely to do anything but make the definition more clear - they wont, for example, make `min-width` do something unexpected like set the color (that is to say, "undefined" still has a very narrow range of outcomes, even if they are sometimes ignored).